# Enable/Disable an image inside an if statement

Tags: unity

Basically i have a code that changes the skybox after killing x amount of enemies, and i want to enable and disable four pictures inside the two if statements. I tried making three public images, set them to false and then enable them inside the every if statement but i'm pretty sure that's not how it works. I'm a noob. Here's the code:

```
public class enemyCount : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int enemiesCount = 15;
    public Material mat1;
    public Material mat2;
    public Material mat3;

    void Start () {
    }


    void  Update (){
        print("Enemy Count is " + enemiesCount); 

        if(enemiesCount <= 10)
        {
            Debug.Log("Level 2!!!");
            RenderSettings.skybox = mat2;
            //Heres should display image number 1 
        }

        if (enemiesCount <= 5) {
            Debug.Log ("Level 3!!!");
            RenderSettings.skybox = mat3;   
            //Here should display image number 2
        }


        if (enemiesCount <= 0) {
            Debug.Log ("YOU WON");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use CopyPropertiesFromMaterial(mat2);